# How would I convert this blob url to some usable form of data?

Tags: url, binary, blob

I have a blob url:

```
blob%3Ahttp%253A//pasteboard.co/1d222521-20a8-4f4a-91c0-7281fe4aa0d8
```

I want to convert this blob url to some usable form of data, like binary, or hex, or anything, because I think it contains an image. I'm only a beginner-novice in programming, so I'm not sure what to do. What do I use in order to convert this blob?

Comment: That doesn't look like a blob so much as just a URL. In other words a blob might be something like an embedded image (ie a [data url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML)) where the data is actually encoded into the data you see. However given what you have, couldn't you just `curl` the image?

Comment: @mlathe how would I do that?

Comment: What do you want to *use* the data to do?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you mean an embedded image like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

(Just copy-paste it into your browser URL, or make an image tag like you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML)